# detect object using switch

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

How to determine if the `value` of a variable is an `object` using `switch`?

```
var alice = condition ? true : {};
switch(alice){
    case true:      break;
    case undefined: break;
    // Is there something like:
    case object:    break;
}
```

I am currently solving the problem above with an additional `if` statement (in addition to my existing `switch` which is already quite large and capable of handling values like `undefined` and `true`). So I was wondering if there is any way of detecting an object using only the existing `switch(alice)`.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  You can create a function that will determine if a variable contains a plain object (and not an array) - it isnt not done with something as simple as a one word `case` statement.  jQuery has such a function in its code if you want to see it.

Comment: Can we see your initial if statements? It's hard to understand the problem you are initially trying to solve from the code you posted.

Comment: Javascript `switch` is not pattern-matching like in Scala or Ruby.

Comment: @plalx its just a `if(typeof alice === 'object') ...` - would be kind of cool to handle it inside the switch directly tough :)

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus If it's a single if statement, why do you need a switch statement? What else do you have in there? ;)

Comment: @palax its switching a lot of `string` values on a central part of a middleware. And some crazy developer invented the case where `alice` could become an object!

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus Well you should just handle that special case independently. That would be way cleaner than trying to integrate it in the switch statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way is not possible. However checking your variable type might help you to accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
var alice = condition ? true : {};
switch (typeof(alice)) {
    case 'boolean': break; // if it's true or false
    case 'undefined': break;
    case 'object': break; // {}, [], {"a": "b"}
}
```

Please note that `object` will also be thrown if you have a non-empty object or an array too.

Comment: `typeof [] == "object"` also.  So your test isn't complete enough if trying to test for `{}`.

Comment: According to the code he shown, his variable can only assume two values: `true` or `{}`. Anyway I will edit the answer to regard this question.

Comment: Then, he might as well just test for `=== true` and be done with it.  Much simpler if something generic is not needed.

Comment: +1 for actually saying `this way is not possible`, I will go with the two dimensional version then, thanks to everyone! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `typeof` operator:

```
switch (typeof alice) {
 // ...
}
```

however note that "true" is not a value that would show up from `typeof` since 'true' is a boolean value, not a type.

So if you must find that out too, you can do like this:

```
switch (typeof alice) {
  case 'object' : 
    // is an object, do something
    break;
  case 'boolean' :
    if (alice) {
      // is true, do something
    }
    break;
  case 'undefined' :
    // is undefined, do something
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
var alice = condition ? true : {};

switch(true){
   case alice === true:      break;
   case alice === undefined: break;
   case alice instanceof Object:    break;
}
```

Comment: My bad for the previous comment, this is actually a pretty elegant solution. :P

Comment: This is incredible! Take my playground if you don't expect this to work: http://jsfiddle.net/YXfZ9/

Answer (score 0):

How about this guy:

```
switch(typeof x)
{ 
  case 'object': alert("object"); break; 
  default: alert("not object");
}
```